# Как решить проблему с расположением по центру в IE

Tags: html, css

Магазин на Webasyst. Сверстал шаблон, верстал обычно, абсолютное позиционирование, но в IE 6-7-8-9 весь сайт прилип к левому краю экрана, `margin: 0 auto;` почему то не сработало. Пришлось выравнивать с помощью `left:50%; margin-left:-половина ширины;` Но тем не менее, футер так и не выровнялся.

Несколько методов выравнивания пробовал, не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<center и align="center" могут центрировать содержимое блоков тоже. А вариант mairgin: 0 auto; работает во всех браузерах, смотрите, скорее всего стили перебиваются.

Comment: Спасибо, решился вопрос извращенным способом, wrapper выравнял с помошью "left:50%" а к футеру применил <center></center>.

Никогда не сталкивался с тэгом <center>.

И кстати тоже не пойму, почему mairgin: 0 auto; отказывается работать только в IE, в остальных все нормально. 

Еще раз спасибо, помогли, продолжу выравнивать остальные блоки!